How to Surface Mount Junction Box on Vinyl Siding?
I am in the process of running electrical to a metal box on the exterior of my house. I've got a weatherproof cable gland and a universal vinyl mounting block. I planned to surface mount the metal box to the mounting block. It seems that this isn't intended (based on this text from Novi block install instructions : "Note: Do not attach accessories directly onto mounting blocks. The fasteners must be attached to a solid surface."), so I plan to add wood to the inside of the mounting block and mount the box to this.
There are standoffs on the back of the box (I bought both metal and plastic, both have this), so I would be sealing the top and sides with silicone to protect the nm coming in the back. The reason I want it surface mounted is to expose the bottom holes so I can run existing conduit to the bottom of the box. I have 3/4" flexible conduit and threaded fittings and to go into the box. Pictures of the box I am replacing are in this question.
I am abandoning that box and adding a new one, attempting to use this mounting block.
Is there a better solution? The only alternative I have found that would allow a recessed box with front entries are for a 1 gang box only (or round), and this isn't very good looking, in my opinion.
TLDR: how best to mount electrical box to a house with vinyl siding such that the bottom entry holes are accessible from below?

I'm not sure you have a question other than your "TDLR"  which would obviously have the common sense answer of, " with the holes at the bottom."   If you are asking how to use a mounting block the idea would be screws would need to go through the block into a solid surface on the side of the home.

Happy to clarify, not sure what I'm missing but can expand on it. The mounting block is intended for the box to be recessed. If the box is recessed, the holes on the bottom of the box will be inaccessible. My question is "how to surface mount the box?".

Mount the box directly to the siding with screws long enough to go through the siding and into the seathing.  just don't tighten the screws so tight that they deform the siding.   BTW your "alternative" is a cover, not any type of box or mounting block.

The alternative is a cover, yes. Not sure where the miscommunication is happening. That alternative would be used if I were to recess the box, since the bottom holes would be obstructed I would use that cover to connect the conduit via the front of the box, rather than the bottom. I do not wish to mount the box directly to the siding. I am planning to reinforce the mounting block to allow mounting to it directly. I am seeking advice to determine if there is a standard or recommended approach to surface mounting a receptacle.

You may be overthinking this.  Mount it to the siding or I have Cut blocks out of 1x4 and painted the color of siding and mounted to that.  There are some preformed "wedge" blocks that are available for siding fixtures, like lights. They can also be used for electric boxes.

Mount the block as intended, to the sheathing beneath the siding—but fill the space behind with wood.  You can either glue/screw the filler to the block, or to the sheathing before installing the block.  Then mount your surface box to the block.

Thank you @Huesmann, that's exactly what I've done https://imgur.com/a/7GBcl8p

Where's the cable going behind the box?

Through a waterproof cable gland, then through the sheathing/sill into my basement. All penetrations surrounded by duct seal.
